# Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PHPExcel_Exception'

Tags: php, excel, codeigniter

I am trying to export some data to excel using php and I am getting the following error.

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PHPExcel_Exception' with message 'Maximum 31    characters allowed in sheet title.' in  C:\xampp\htdocs\doc\application\third_party\PHPExcel\Worksheet.php:472.

Is there any way to increase the title length from 31 to another digit?
Somebody please help.

Comment: I doubt it, since even Excel (the actual application) won't let you enter more characters than that in a sheet title.

Comment: There seems to be some discussion [here on github](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/issues/79) about this and some work arounds

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just go to PHPExcel\Worksheet.php file and comment the following line:

```
if (PHPExcel_Shared_String::CountCharacters($pValue) > 31) {
    throw new PHPExcel_Exception('Maximum 31 characters allowed in sheet title.');
}
```

Comment: This worked for me.Changing that 31 to another value is also working fine.Thank you

Comment: This might break every time we will run composer update, also I will have to do this manually on every server and dev machines.

Comment: But why is it 31 ? That magical number should be defined in a constant somewhere =/

Answer (score 3):

Opening the Worksheet.php file, I added the following to the top of the public `function setTitle($pValue = ‘Worksheet’)` method:

```
$pValue = substr($pValue, 0, 31);
```

Comment: Modifying vendor files isn't a viable option in my case but this answer helped me cap the title when setting it in the first place. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Open your PHPExcel\Worksheet.php file and `change the value 31 to some other digit` in the following line of code:

```
if (PHPExcel_Shared_String::CountCharacters($pValue) > 31) {
    throw new PHPExcel_Exception('Maximum 31 characters allowed in sheet title.');
}
```